# Is there a formula that converts a number from 0 to 959 to a corresponding chess960 position?

Tags: chess-variants, mathematics, chess960

I am looking into a [website](http://www.mark-weeks.com/cfaa/chess960/c960strt.htm) with starting positions for chess960.

```
000 BBQNNRKR
001 BQNBNRKR
002 BQNNRBKR
003 BQNNRKRB
004 QBBNNRKR
005 QNBBNRKR
...
959 RKRNNQBB
```

So there is a table that converts any number from 0 to 959 to a starting position. For example `chess960(518) = 'RNBQKBNR'` normal starting chess position.

What is this formula? How can I do this without storing all the table?

Comment: The chess960 sites show you how to do it. Generate them and store them. Then you won't have to calculate them every time.

Comment: Are you writing a chess program?

Comment: @wes yes, I am writing a chess server. I want to add ability to play chess960. Currently I have a list of all positions as a list, but having 960 elements is not really nice, especially if there is some formula which can convert a number to this 8 digit string.

Comment: @SalvadorDali why not nice? If you store them in an array it's less than 8KB. Very performance efficient for a server doing a simple O(1) lookup.

Comment: I wanted a more elegant approach. O(1) looks good from theoretical computer science approach. I hardly doubt that a formula would be that hard. Even if it would be O(n^2) which is highly unlikely for 960 elements even with the crapiest computer right now will run less than 0.1 second. I was also curious how  this convention appeared, so it is not only about my chess program. Thanks for taking a look at my problem.

Answer (score 10):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess960_numbering_scheme#Direct_derivation):

> White's Chess960 starting array can be derived from its number N (0
>   ... 959) as follows:
>
> a) Divide N by 4, yielding quotient N2 and remainder B1. Place a
>   Bishop upon the bright square corresponding to B1 (0=b, 1=d, 2=f,
>   3=h).
>
> b) Divide N2 by 4 again, yielding quotient N3 and remainder B2. Place
>   a second Bishop upon the dark square corresponding to B2 (0=a, 1=c,
>   2=e, 3=g).
>
> c) Divide N3 by 6, yielding quotient N4 and remainder Q. Place the
>   Queen according to Q, where 0 is the first free square starting from
>   a, 1 is the second, etc.
>
> d) N4 will be a single digit, 0 ... 9. Place the Knights according to
>   its value by consulting the following table:
>
> ```
> 0     N   N   -   -   -
> 1     N   -   N   -   -
> 2     N   -   -   N   -
> 3     N   -   -   -   N
> 4     -   N   N   -   -
> 5     -   N   -   N   -
> 6     -   N   -   -   N
> 7     -   -   N   N   -
> 8     -   -   N   -   N
> 9     -   -   -   N   N
> ```
>
> e) There are three blank squares remaining; place a Rook in each of
>   the outer two and the King in the middle one.